# Can it be shown mathematically that $\|Wrelu(W_{d-1}relu(\ldots relu(W_x))\|\leq\|W_{d-1}W_d\ldots W_1x\|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, neural-networks

Let $W_1,W_2, \ldots W_d$ be linear transformations. Also, let $relu(x)=\max(0,x)$ be an element wise non linearity. Can we somehow show that 
\begin{equation}
\|Wrelu(W_{d-1}relu(\ldots relu(W_x))\|\leq\|W_{d-1}W_d\ldots W_1x\|
\end{equation}
here $\|.\|$ is an $\ell_2$ norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is true. Let $W_1$ be the identity, $W_2(x_1,x_2) = (x_1+x_2, 0)$. Then
$$W_2W_1(-1,1) = W_2(-1,1) = (0,0)$$
while
$$W_2(relu(W_1(-1,1)) = W_2(relu(-1,1)) = W_2(0,1) = (1,0).$$